# How can I get ushort?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, types, sqldatareader

```
ID = reader.GetInt16(2) //ID: ushort
```

Will give me the error Error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'short' to 'ushort'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

What is the best practice to get the data without changing my property to short?

Comment: What would you like to do when the value is negative? What is the database column type?

Comment: 1) Read the error message, 2) Do what it says. 3) Problem solved.

Comment: The value is pre-defined with positive numbers only. The column type is smallint.

Comment: @Soner: I know the error message, asked because was not sure if casting would be the only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, you can cast to `ushort`:

```
ID = (ushort) reader.GetInt16(2);
```